# Appending New Row to Table is Duplicating <tr>

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get Google Map locations lat and long value into a table at this <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/BLzTN/1/)**</kbd> but I don't know why jquery is duplicating the table row?

Here is the code I am using:

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var cnt = 0;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Camp Num: " + ++cnt
        });
           $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td></tr>');
    });

});
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tbody indicates body of element and browsers insert tbody element in the table. If you look elements using chrome inspector tools or firebug, you can see two tbody in your table. Therefore, you see two rows being appended in two tbody. You can write something like this:

```
 $('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class="child"><td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Thanks KrishnaDhungana,